# How is the variable importance of the GBM model calculated in the h2o package?

Tags: h2o, gbm

I would like to know, what is the specific method / formula to calculate the variable importance of the GBM model in h2o package, both for continuous and categorical variables.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever a node is split based on a column/feature/variable (either numeric or categorical), the reduction in squared error attributed to the split (squared error in one "mixed" node before - sum of squared error in two "purer" nodes afterwards) is counted towards the absolute variable importance. It gets scaled afterwards such that the largest variable importance is 1.0.